# Multi project build: execute function for every subproject

Tags: gradle, junit, junit5

I have this folder structure:

- project/subproject1
- project/subproject2
- project/subproject3
- project/build.gradle (root config)

Every subproject has its own build.gradle config. 
I have got some tests in subproject 1 and 3 (subproject 2 does not contain any tests, I am not sure if this information is required for my question).

I use JUnit5 in my tests. In order to execute them while building the project I added this in each of my build.gradle in my subprojects.

```
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Everything works fine, all the tests are being executed but I dont want to touch each of the config files for this small snippet. I want to have something common for this.

I have been trying to do the docs from [gradle-docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:subproject_configuration) but without success.

This is what I am trying to add in my root build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    tasks.test(){
        doLast {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
}
```

But it either says, that 'test' is already defined or something like "Could not find method test() for arguments [buildClosure] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following in project/build.gradle

```
subprojects {
   apply plugin : 'java'
   test.useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Now, the test task is configured in the root project to use the junit5 for all its subproject. Notice, 'java' plugin applied for subprojects as well. Now, any subproject is pre-configured at the root project level itself.

Comment: Works for me! Why do I need the java part exactly? Without applying the java plugin I get an this error message: "Could not get unknown property 'test' for project 'subproject2' of type org.gradle.api.Project. Note: this subproject2 does not contain any tests.

Comment: Gradle task ```test``` is provided by the ```plugin: java```. Applying the 'java' plugin in the root/build.gradle means that you can skip declaring plugin: 'java' in your subprojects as well.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve been thinking too complicated. It’s easier. Just add

```
subprojects {
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

to your project‘s top level `build.gradle` file. You can add (mostly) anything to this block that should be done in each sub project.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I assume its because there is a subproject without any tests.

Comment: You additionally need to apply the java plugin as shown intel other answer. I had assumed you already did that otherwise your initial code wouldn’t have worked either.